# How to cache Dataframe in Apache ignite

Tags: scala, hadoop, caching, apache-spark, ignite

I am writing a code to cache RDBMS data using spark SQLContext JDBC connection. Once a Dataframe is created I want to cache that reusltset using apache ignite thereby making other applications to make use of the resultset. Here is the code snippet.

```
object test
{

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {

      val configuration = new Configuration()
      val config="src/main/scala/config.xml"

      val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf)
      val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      val sql_dump1=sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc URL").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", mysql_table_statement).option("user", "username").option("password", "pass").load()

      val ic = new IgniteContext[Integer, Integer](sc, config)

      val sharedrdd = ic.fromCache("hbase_metadata")

      //How to cache sql_dump1 dataframe

  }
}
```

Now the question is how to cache a dataframe, IgniteRDD has savepairs method but it accepts key and value as RDD[Integer], but I have a dataframe even if I convert that to RDD i would only be getting RDD[Row]. The savepairs method consisting of RDD of Integer seems to be more specific what if I have a string of RDD as value?  Is it good to cache dataframe or any other better approach to cache the resultset.

Comment: Hey Vignesh, did you get any other solution for this? or you went by below approach only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to store `DataFrame` in an Ignite cache (shared RDD) since you won't benefit from it too much: at least you won't be able to execute [Ignite SQL](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#section-running-sql-queries-against-ignite-cache) over the `DataFrame`.

I would suggest doing the following:

- provide [`CacheStore`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store) implementation for hbase_metadata cache that will preload all the data from your underlying database. Then you can preload all the data into the cache using `Ignite.loadCache` method. [Here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc) you may find an example on how to use JDBC persistent stores along with Ignite cache (shared RDD)

  - use [Ignite Shared RDD sql](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#section-running-sql-queries-against-ignite-cache) api to query over cached data.

Alternatively you can get sql_dump1 as you're doing, iterate over each row and store each row individually in the shared RDD using `IgniteRDD.savePairs` method. After this is done you can query over data using the same Ignite Shared RDD SQL mentioned above.