# Cache Dataframe with Apache Ignite RDD using scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

Have a dataframe that reads data from oracle db. I need to cache this dataframe to Ignite Shared RDD so it can be accessed across multiple sesssions. I tried the solution posted in "[How to cache Dataframe in Apache ignite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180715/how-to-cache-dataframe-in-apache-ignite)". Lookslike the loadCache() api's are available in java. Am not able to find the loadCache() method in scala when I import the libraries. Any info on this will help. Thanks, VM

Answer (score 0):

`loadCache()` method is on `IgniteCache` API, not `Ignite`. Looks like there is a mistake in that response. All Java APIs can be used in Scala.

Comment: Tried importing "org.apache.ignite.cache.store.CacheStore", and "org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache" but see only "asInstanceOf   isInstanceOf   toString" methods in both the cases, donot see loadCache() method. Any thoughts ? Thanks

Comment: If you don't have any methods on `IgniteCache`, you're definitely doing something wrong. Java and Scala are fully compatible, you can use any Java classes with all their APIs from Scala. Ignite is not an exception here.